# swift UITextFieldDelegate extension

Tags: ios, swift, custom-controls, uitextfielddelegate

I am fairly new with swift and I can't understand the following situation. I am trying to extends the UIViewController class with with a couple of UITextFieldDelegate functions...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.delegate = self
```

In another file, if I define the function with the parameter unwrapped, the function is not called...

```
extension UIViewController: UITextFieldDelegate{

    internal func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        print("Text Field Should Begin Editing called")
        return true
    }
```

but if I unwrap the parameter, it WORKS.

```
    internal func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField!) -> Bool
```

can you please help me to understand why? 
thank you

swift 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Objective-C does not make any guarantees that an object is non-nil, Swift makes all classes in argument types and return types optional in imported Objective-C APIs. Before you use an Objective-C object, you should check to ensure that it is not missing.

If you use `_ textField: UITextField` the parameter can be null, hence the method is not invoked by the delegate as its looking for a non null value within method signature i.e     `internal func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField!) -> Bool`

Answer (score 0):

In your extension file, you should be extending *your* ViewController class, rather than the UIViewController class.  You don't need the force unwrapped.  So it should look like this:

```
extension UIViewController: UITextFieldDelegate{
    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
         print("Should begin editing!")   
    }
}
```